# fixing 'no matching overloaded function found'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, webview2

What compiler setting(s) do I need to set in order to avoid:

> Error C2672 'unbox_value_type': no matching overloaded function found C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\cppwinrt\winrt\Windows.Foundation.h 2901

The `Windows.Foundation.h` file is read only, and I'd like to keep it that way.

I'm trying to create a Windows application that uses WebView2.
I installed VS2022 (free version), downloaded the WebView2 sample (the sample solution builds OK). I created a new project, and I'm trying to add fragments to it from the sample, but the compiler errors out on the file mentioned above, on line 2901.

Comment: Please show a [mre]. Did you `#include <Unknwn.h>` before any cppwinrt header to enable classic COM support?

Comment: There should be more of the error message (check the Output window) that explains what overloads were found and why none of them were suitable.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo: your solution (`#include <Unknwn.h>`) is what was needed. Many thanks.

Comment: Please post your response as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @RaymondChen All I have  to lean on are _your_ articles, but I made it into an answer. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: Look further in the error log. The error was detected at 2901, but it was probably triggered by something in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`#include <unknwn.h>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/) before any cppwinrt header to enable classic COM support.

Useful reading (both articles written by [Raymond Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen)):

- [Why does C++/WinRT say that `first_interface` is not a member of `winrt::impl::interface_list<>`?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220323-00/?p=106378)

  > I noted that by default C++/WinRT requires interfaces to derive from `winrt::Windows::Foundation::IUnknown`. You can activate nondefault behavior by including the **`unknwn.h`** header file before including any C++/WinRT header files, in which case C++/WinRT will also recognize types which derives from classic COM `IUnknown` as interfaces.
- [The various ways of moving between C++/WinRT and classic COM](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210830-00/?p=105617)